# how to always route <anything>.local to 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache, xampp, virtual, virtualhost, host

backgroumd: apparently all domains I "ping" in terminal ending with `.dev` will be "routed" (or resolved) to `127.0.0.1` but strangely I've read .dev is owned by google?

anyhow: my goal is to use a dynamic virtual hosts setup with my xammp so I can just use for example:

http://route-to-my-website.local and it will automatically open up a website with document root using the "route-to-my-website" subfolder. this works already, using the

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/<my-user-name>/Sites/%-2+"
```

Setting when my computer is resolving the domain to 127.0.0.1 by setting in the etc/hosts

My Question is, can I somehow dynamically set my `etc/hosts` dynamically so I dont have to enter all my projects there manually?

Just using .dev as an option doesnt work because it always redirects to `https`

Comment: Have you tried *.local ?

Comment: No I didn't try, but I think I did found the "term" I was looking for, its called "wildcards" and I found some tips now on serverfault